# implementing addOnProgressListener In Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my code i want to add `OnProgressListener`, but can't work. It gives me a syntax error.
Cannot resolve method 'addOnProgressListener' in 'Task'

How i can do this?
Please rewrite the code for me.

I Want to show progress dialog percentage.
For example:  "uploading video  98%"

```
private void uploadImage_10() {
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Posting....");
    pd.show();
    if (video_url != null) {
        final StorageReference fileReference = storageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(video_url));

        uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(video_url);

        String desc = description.getText().toString();
        if (desc.length() < 20) {
            description.setError("Please Insert Document to long");
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(desc)) {
                description.setError("Please insert Description");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Insert Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            pd.dismiss();
        } else {
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        miUrlOk = downloadUri.toString();

                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://pineka-social-media-mast-da52a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
                        ).getReference("Posts_video");

                        String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
                        hashMap.put("time_post", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                        hashMap.put("postvideo", miUrlOk);
                        hashMap.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("category", category.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                        reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);

                        pd.dismiss();

                        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivityvideo.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivityvideo.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivityvideo.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    progressDialog.setMessage((int) progress + "");
                }
            });
            
            
            
            
            
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(PostActivityvideo.this, "No image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to already be determining the `progress` value. What isn't working about it? If you get an error message, what is the exact message? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: msg : Cannot resolve method 'addOnProgressListener' in 'Task'

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you may have defined `uploadTask` as a `Task`.

To be able to call `addOnProgressListener` ,you'll want to declare it as an `UploadTask`.

Comment: Can you rewrite the code without UploadTask?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. You need `UploadTask`, or at the very least `StorageTask`, as *that* is where `addOnProgressListener` is defined: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTask